# MS Access Updating Oracle Database - Query Problems

Tags: sql, oracle, ms-access, sql-update

I am currently having a problem with an update query which updates one column in one of our Oracle tables. Basically we import a CSV file into Access, call it 'NewULN' then the criteria from this file is used to update our table.

This script works fine if you're entering person codes manually. It updates the table accordingly with the correct results. The code for this is below:

```
UPDATE NewULN INNER JOIN FES_PEOPLE ON NewULN.MISIdentifier = FES_PEOPLE.PERSON_CODE SET FES_PEOPLE.UNIQUE_LEARN_NO = [NewULN].[ULN]
WHERE (NewULN.ULN Is Not Null) AND (FES_PEOPLE.PERSON_CODE=[Enter Person Code]);
```

We now wish to update all records in one go but we have always had difficulties doing this. Here's me thinking this code below would be ok:

Orginal Code:

```
UPDATE NewULN INNER JOIN FES_PEOPLE ON NewULN.MISIdentifier = FES_PEOPLE.PERSON_CODE SET FES_PEOPLE.UNIQUE_LEARN_NO = [NewULN].[ULN]
WHERE (NewULN.ULN Is Not Null) AND (FES_PEOPLE.PERSON_CODE=NewULN.MISIdentifier);
```

Most up to date version (based on suggestions):

```
UPDATE NewULN INNER JOIN FES_PEOPLE ON NewULN.MISIdentifier = FES_PEOPLE.PERSON_CODE SET FES_PEOPLE.UNIQUE_LEARN_NO = [NewULN].[ULN]
WHERE (NewULN.ULN Is Not Null);
```

But we've had all sorts of errors crop up - sometimes Access will just crash when you try and run the access query.

Sometimes it will come up with lock violations (interestingly enough it'll update the first record, then fail all the rest). Sometimes an error "FES_PEOPLE - 'invalid number'" pops up, other times "Can bind a long value only for insert into a long column".

The field ULN has always been Text and it has always worked before, MISIdentifier was always Text as well (When we had a running version of this on Windows XP) but now I have changed it to a Long Int.

I didn't write this orginally, it stopped working after we upgraded our machines to Windows 7 so I am now having to rewrite it with very little knowledge of Access.

Thanks for any replies that I get in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that creating a new Access Database and relinking all of tables again enabled this query to work. There was nothing wrong with the syntax :-)

Answer (score 1):

In your second query you are already doing a JOIN on `NewULN.MISIdentifier = FES_PEOPLE.PERSON_CODE` so also including that condition in your WHERE clause is redundant. Perhaps that is throwing a wrench into the works?

Comment: Thanks for your input, I didn't even notice that. I took out the bit in the WHERE clause and ran the update but got a lock violation error. It updated the first record again, but failed on the other 67.

New code:
UPDATE NewULN INNER JOIN FES_PEOPLE ON NewULN.MISIdentifier = FES_PEOPLE.PERSON_CODE SET FES_PEOPLE.UNIQUE_LEARN_NO = [NewULN].[ULN]
WHERE (NewULN.ULN Is Not Null);

Answer (score 0):

What ODBC driver are you using to connect to Oracle? If using the Microsoft for Oracle driver, try using an Oracle driver instead. The MS driver has not been updated since version 7 and should not be used.